# How to shortly define a letter in vim regex that includes regional diacritics without directly enumerating them?

Tags: regex, vim

The `[a-z]` regex set is superb, but it doesn't include regional characters.

Is it possible in Vim to define in more concise way a letter set which included local characters (in my case, Polish one) without directly enumerating them?

```
[a-zA-ZąęóśćźżńłĄĘÓŚĆŹŻŃŁ]
```

Use case below:

https://regex101.com/r/9y0XlH/1

Why?

It is tedious and error prone to do it directly.

Comment: `\k` matches all of those here, but it depends on your `iskeyword` setting.

Comment: What about using Unicode!

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/60600

Answer (score 0):

The characters ranges appear to work over unicode code point values (tested on vim 8.0 huge version). Assuming that you only want to type characters on your polish keyboard, **use `[a-zA-ZÓóĄ-ż]` to match any of the characters you gave.** Note that this matches non-polish characters, for example `Œ` matches because it is between Ą and ż in code point values.

The method I used to construct that regrex was to look at the Unicode blocks for the characters you want and then picking the type-able character with the smallest code point and the type-able character with the largest code point in each block. Divide these into smaller ranges if you don't want to match some character between those characters. For example when trying to match all the Icelandic characters in Latin-1, to keep from matching × and ÷, you would need to use three ranges. One to match the letters before ×, one to match between × and ÷, and one to match after ÷. This will of course still match many non-Icelandic characters, but the other characters matched will be letters at least.

Since Unicode in arrange by language to some extent, I was able to look for the block which added support for Polish (Latin Extended-A) as a starting point. Then I had to add Ó and ó from Latin-1 to get all the characters for Polish which aren't in a-zA-Z.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
/[^ ]\+
```

This match any character except "white-space", you can play whit this.